# Making a dictionary from a file in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary with actor names as keys, and the movies they're in as the value

The file looks like this:

```
Brad Pitt,Sleepers,Troy,Meet Joe Black,Oceans Eleven,Seven,Mr & Mrs Smith
Tom Hanks,You have got mail,Apollo 13,Sleepless in Seattle,Catch Me If You Can
```

And I want this to be the output:

```
{Brad Pitt : Sleepers,Troy,Meet Joe Black,Oceans Eleven,Seven,Mr & Mrs Smith
Tom Hanks : You have got mail,Apollo 13,Sleepless in Seattle,Catch Me If You Can}
```

I think my problem is that I can't access the file for some reason, although it's certainly possible there's some other problem with my code that I'm not seeing. Here's what I have:

```
from Myro import *
    def makeDictionaryFromFile():
    dictionary1={}
    try:
        infile = open("films.txt","r")
        nextLineFromFile = infile.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
        while (nextLineFromFile != ""):
            line = nextLineFromFile.split(",")
            first=line[0]
            dictionary1[first]=line[1:]
            nextLineFromFile = infile.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
    except:
        print ("File not found! (or other error!)")
    return dictionary1
```

Comment: Your file appears to be a CSV file; you might like to look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module. Also, you should fix your code formatting (indentation).

Comment: Catch the exception and print it to help determine the problem.  "except Exception as e: print e"

Comment: firstly, your try block be more specific. Also, it would be helpful to print error message in the except clause. `except Exception as e: print e`

Comment: cryo and phani, thanks for that. It says "[Errno 2] Could not find file "/Users/name/csci/films.txt".: films.txt
{}"

Comment: Check if the file is in that directory and has proper read access.

Comment: what do you mean by proper read access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start using the super helpful `ipdb` module.

```
try:
  # some error
except Exception as e:
  print e
  import ipdb
  ipdb.set_trace()
```

If you get used to this process, it will help you a lot in this as well as future debugging.

Comment: thanks, i found the problem. it was just an error in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mydict = {}
f = open('file','r')
for x in f:
    s = s.strip('\r\n').split(',')
    mydict[s[0]] = ",".join(s[1:])
print mydict
```

`s[0]` will have actor name, `s[1:]` is all his films name

you using `readline` readline only read a line.suppose below is a file called `test.txt`

```
Hello stackoverflow
hello Hackaholic
```

code:

```
f=open('test.txt')
print f.readline()
print f.readline()
```

output:

```
Hello stackoverflow
hello Hackaholic
```

you need to also put your `readline` in side while loop, and you also need to do some other changes.

Comment: why can't I use the while loop i have?

Comment: the problem is you using `readline` it reads only one line at a time

Comment: but it's iterating over every line, right? so it should add add each line to the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> dictionary1 = {}
>>> for curr_line in open("films.txt").xreadlines():
...     split_line = curr_line.strip().split(",")
...     dictionary1[split_line.pop(0)] = split_line

>>> dictionary1
{'Brad Pitt': ['Sleepers', 'Troy', 'Meet Joe Black', 'Oceans Eleven', 'Seven', 'Mr & Mrs Smith'], 'Tom Hanks': ['You have got mail', 'Apollo 13', 'Sleepless in Seattle', 'Catch Me If You Can']}
```